# Select all rows containing today's date and send email with reminder

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select a range of rows containing current date and paste into email body to send an email with reminder.

The code I used selected only the cells containing the current date.
I need the whole rows to be selected and pasted into the email body.

The date is added into "D" column range.

The outcome should be:
Every day, the macro should run automatically, do a check of the date and the rows containing current date, then send an email to specific recipient.

More likely I want to automate this selection:

```vb
Sub EmailRange()
'Update 20131209
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Range Selection" 
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection 
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8) 
WorkRng.Select 
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    .Introduction = "Hello," & vbNewLine & "deadline has been reached!" & vbNewLine & \_
      "Please, send a reminder!"
    .Item.To = "email@email"
    .Item.CC = "email@email"
    .Item.Subject = "Issue reminder " & Range("C" & 3).Value
    .Item.Send
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I cannot automate the selection and need to select the range manually.
I want automatic selection based on current date.

Answer (score 0):

Pls try.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub EmailRange()
    'Update 20131209
    Dim c As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify sheet name as needed
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each c In .Range("D1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            If IsDate(c.Value) Then
                If c.Value = Date Then
                    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
                    With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
                        .Introduction = "Hello," & vbNewLine & "deadline has been reached!" & _
                            vbNewLine & "Please, send a reminder!"
                        .Item.To = "email@email"
                        .Item.CC = "email@email"
                        .Item.Subject = "Issue reminder " & .Range("C" & 3).Value
                        .Item.Send
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reaching out! When i ran the macro, the file closed and outlook bugged so i needed to close the process manually. I will put some edits and screenshot of the sheet as a final step. Thank you for the effort, really!

Comment: I haven't seen the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

With these modifications the valid content of the row where the today date is, will be sent in the email after the Introduction text.

```
Sub EmailRange()
'Update 20131209
Dim WorkRng As Range
'On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Range Selection"
'Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
'Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set WorkRng = ActiveSheet.columns("D").Find(Int(Now))
If WorkRng Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "There is no today date in column D!", vbOKOnly, "WARNING!"
  Exit Sub
End If
'WorkRng.Select
lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(WorkRng.Row, columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(WorkRng.Row, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(WorkRng.Row, lastcol)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
.Introduction = "Hello," & vbNewLine & "deadline has been reached!" & vbNewLine & _
"Please, send a reminder!"
.item.To = "email@email"
.item.CC = "email@email"
.item.Subject = "Issue reminder " & Range("C" & 3).Value
.item.send
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

EDIT: Insert Message for missing date.

```
Sub EmailRange()
'Update 20131209
Dim WorkRng As Range
'On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Range Selection"
'Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
'Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set WorkRng = ActiveSheet.columns("D").Find(Int(Now), , xlValues)
'WorkRng.Select
If WorkRng Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "There is no today date in column D!", vbOKOnly, "WARNING!"
  Exit Sub
End If
Set firstcell = WorkRng
Set nextcell = WorkRng
Do
lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(nextcell.Row, columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(nextcell.Row, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(nextcell.Row, lastcol)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
.Introduction = "Hello," & vbNewLine & "deadline has been reached!" & vbNewLine & _
"Please, send a reminder!"
.item.To = "email@email"
.item.CC = "email@email"
.item.Subject = "Issue reminder " & Range("C" & 3).Value
.item.send
End With
Set nextcell = ActiveSheet.columns("D").FindNext(nextcell)
Loop Until nextcell.Address = firstcell.Address
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The second code looks for all occurences of the today date and accept formula result in the cells.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got an error on this line: 'lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(WorkRng.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column' Object variable or with block variable not set. #justamateurthings Thanks for helping out! :) :) :)

Comment: Maybe there is no today date in column D. Added message for it in code.

Comment: Omg i'm so stupid :D, the date is generated with a formula. The file logs issues and based on today's date generates automatically date for project deadline. I need the lines that reach deadline and i'm using this formula to generate the date in column D: 
'=IF(C1="","",WORKDAY(C1, 2))" 

Maybe that's the reason the code didn't work.

Comment: Try this in the code replace this `Find(Int(Now))` to this `Find(Int(Now)-1462)

Comment: Hmm, didn't work. I edit to 'Set WorkRng = Range("D:D").Find(What:=Int(Now), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) , but it's selecting only the first row with the current date.

Comment: Then  find the date. What didn't work? Not send the email? Range("D:D") is the same as ActiveSheet.Columns("D").

Comment: It returned that there's no date in column D

Comment: OK. Because of the formula apply `Find(Int(Now),,xlValues)`

Comment: Now it worked, but it's selecting only the first row. I will try by myself as well, but the help is really appreciated. :)

Comment: I added the code for looking for every occurences in the answer.

Comment: For every row containing current date i got email, but with first row pasted in the body.

Comment: Ooops! I didn't change the `Workrng` to `nextcell` in the `Do Loop` Edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did work. Now it's sending separate email for each row containing the date. Can we make it somehow to paste the whole selection in one email instead of going over every row and sending separate emails? Thanks for your time, normally it costs money. :)

Comment: Yes, but excel cannot send non adjacent cells in one email, so first collect the partial result in one block, then select the collected block and send it via email.